# How to display "₹" indian rupee symbol in visualforce page which is rendered as PDF?

Tags: visualforce, renderas

I'm able to display "₹" Indian rupee symbol in the visualforce page either by hard coding or by using some 5 digit code. But the same VF page when rendered as PDF "₹" Indian rupee symbol won't display. May I know how to display "₹" symbol in PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already tried that and it is not supported as of now. So you can't use that. Some workaround which you can use is either display INR or make a small PNG of Ruppe symbol and then conditional display that image. Not a good choice but you can use if you don't have any other choice else you can go with INR.

Here is a code sample in case someone want to try this.

```
<apex:page renderas="pdf">
    ₹
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This is not working, I am seeing a blank PDF, Has something changed after these many years ?

Answer (score 1):

Upload ₹ Indian Rupee Symbol in image format,into static resource and use it where ever you want in vf page by calling the static sresource

```
<apex:page renderas="pdf">
<div align="left"><apex:image url="{!$Resource.Rupee}" width="10" height="10"/></div>
```